# How to return a value from psql to bash and use it?

Tags: postgresql, psql

Suppose I created a sequence in postgresql:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE my_seq;
```

I store the below line in an sql file get_seq.sql

```
SELECT last_value FROM my_seq;

$SUDO psql -q -d database_bame -f get_seq.sql
```

How do I get the int number returned by SELECT into bash and use it?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

You can capture the result of a command using the VAR=$(command) syntax:

```
VALUE=$(psql -qtAX -d database_name -f get_seq.sql)
echo $VALUE
```

The required psql options mean:

`-t` only tuple

`-A` output not unaligned

`-q` quiet

`-X` Don't run .psqlrc file

Comment: @eric-leschinski, why did you add the `-X` option? I think, this option in not needed in this case.

Comment: The `~/.psqlrc` file performs operations upon database login that dump noise to the output which is caught up into your `VALUE` variable, that noise was removed with the -X option.

Comment: ok, this was you case, but is it generally valid? The psqlrc file could also perform operations which are needed for running the query

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
LAST_VALUE=`echo "SELECT last_value FROM my_seq;" | psql -qAt -d database_name`
```