# COPY command do not export json format properly

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to export a column type jsonb using the copy command as follow:

```
payload
-------
{"test": "testing"}

sudo -u postgres psql test_database -c "COPY (SELECT payload FROM test_table) TO STDIN CSV"
```

The output gives me quoted text which is not a correct json format:

```
"{""test"":""testing""}"
```

How can I get a correct json format ?

Comment: It looks like you've chosen [CSV output format](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-copy.html#id-1.9.3.55.9.3), which escapes quotes that way. `COPY` does not produce JSON.

Comment: For JSON embedded in CSV, that *is* the correct format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've chosen [CSV output format](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-copy.html#id-1.9.3.55.9.3), which escapes quotes that way. `COPY` does not produce JSON.

Do not use `COPY` to get the output, rather see [store postgresql result in bash variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15242752/1048572) or [How to return a value from psql to bash and use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28451598/1048572):

```
psql -U postgres -d test_database -AXqtc "SELECT payload FROM test_table;"
```

Comment: Is it possible to set the delimiter and NULL values ? i.e DELIMITER '~' NULL 'null' ?

Comment: @pikk For `COPY`? Yes, but it'll still use escaping for it.

Comment: No i mean with your solution...

Comment: You can `COALESCE(payload, 'null'::jsonb)`. And I think there's no delimiter if you select only a single column?

Comment: If i SELECT more columns , is it possible to set DELIMITER?

Comment: According to [the `psql` docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html), `-F` (and `-z`) do that. Apparently you can also run `\pset null 'null'; SELECT …;` to change the `NULL` output